# Views not being removed from Superview when Selector method called

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

For my app, I have a UIToolBar that appears above a UIWebView. What I'm attempting to do is remove both the tool-bar and the web-view from the superview when UIBarButtonItem in the tool-bar is clicked.

I've made the tool-bar and web-view properties of my ViewController like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIToolbar *toolBar;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIWebView *webView;
```

These views are supposed to be removed when the method below is called

```
// Remove the toolbar and the webview 
- (void)hideToolbarAndWebView
{
    [_toolBar removeFromSuperview];
    [_webView removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"Button clicked");
}
```

Below is where I'm first creating the bar-button item, and assigning the action to be the hideToolbarAndWebView method:

```
// Create a bar button and add it to the toolbar. Action is to dismiss the tool-bar and thew web-view.
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(hideToolbarAndWebView)];
```

I know that the bar-button is successfully calling the hideToolbarAndWebView method through logging, but the views are not being removed from the superview. How do I fix this?

**EDIT** Below is the code where the tool-bar is created. It's inside a method called `showToolbar`that is called from the AppDelegate.

```
// Create a toolbar
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
// Default height is 44 points, but seems to close to the status bar
toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),64);
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Below is the code that creates the web-view, and calls the above `showToolbar`method:

```
 // Create a web view that displays the update info, and save settings for current version
    SWWebViewController *webViewController = [[SWWebViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *url=@"http://google.com";
    webViewController.URL = url;
    webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [webViewController showToolbar];
```

Comment: `toolBar` and `webView` will be nil

Comment: You're right @MidhunMP; I just checked the value of the views with NSLog.

Comment: How did you added those to your interface by code ? If yes, can you show that code ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes, I just updated my question.

Comment: You created a local variable for the toolbar and webview, so how can you remove that using the global property ? (You didn't even assigned that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Midhun MP, I realized what I was doing wrong. Instead of trying to use properties, I needed to set `toolBar` and `webView` to be global variables:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar;
UIWebView *webView;
```

And instead of creating `toolBar` and `webView` like so:

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
SWWebViewController *webViewController = [[SWWebViewController alloc] init];
```

Since the variables were now created, I now only needed to assign them like so:

```
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];   
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Then, when I called `hideToolbarAndWebView`, the `toolBar` and `webView` were both removed from the superview.